# Spawn thread and do something else while it's running for as long as it's active

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I have a simple program below where some long running process `someFn` works, sets a state, works sets a state, works and sets a state.

While `someFn` is running, I want the main thread to query the state it's setting for the lifetime of `someFn`.

Obviously this code is incorrect because `T` is `joinable` until it actually joins and this program does not halt.

How do I correctly get the main thread to loop for the lifetime of `T` and stop looping as soon as `T` has terminated?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int STATE = 0;
static std::mutex mtx;

void setState(int newState) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
    STATE = newState;
}

int getState() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
    return STATE;
}


void someFn() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    setState(0);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    setState(1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    setState(2);
}

int main()
{

    std::thread T(someFn);

    while (T.joinable()) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << getState() << std::endl;
    }

    T.join();

    return 0;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `while( getState() != 2)`  ?!? I think I dont understand the question

Comment: Sure that works in this specific example but let's assume I don't know what the end state is. I just want to know when `T` has terminated.

Comment: somehow the thread has to signal that it is done with its job. If you dont know the final value of `state` then use some `bool taskDone` either as `std::atomic<bool>` or protected by mutex

Comment: Sounds like you could be looking for [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just with `std::thread` you can't.

But you can easily craft your own signal. For example:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int STATE = 0;
static std::mutex mtx;

void setState(int newState) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
    STATE = newState;
}

int getState() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
    return STATE;
}

void someFn(std::atomic<bool>& isDone) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    setState(0);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    setState(1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    setState(2);
    isDone.store(true);
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<bool> isDone{false};
    std::thread T(someFn, std::ref(isDone));

    while(!isDone.load()) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << getState() << std::endl;
    }

    T.join();

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need a mutex or other synchronization for `std::atomic` because it is already thread safe.

Comment: [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) for `STATE `may be able to simplify this somewhat.

Comment: You need to wrap the `isDone` argument into a `std::ref`. Otherwise you get an error because of the implicit argument copying that `std::thread`'s constructor does.

Comment: @uneven_mark I was editing that in while you commented I notice. :-)